# Pop-up window for picture/link function on ck editor on chrome and IE not appearing correctly

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, ckeditor

I am using CK editor on my application to edit html pages. It allows me to open and edit without any issues,  but if I try to add image or link another pop-up window opens in behind, but I am unable to edit as its sitting in behind.(please see attached picture) This is happening on chrome Version 40.0.2214.93. In IE browser the pop-up window appears right but it freezes and doesn't allow me to make any changes.

I tried to look for this error but I only found suggestion to change on configuration to basic load...I don't know how to do this, plus I am not sure if this will resolve my issue as I don't want a basic view.

Please let me know if you have any queries regarding to my question.

Thanks

[image: CK Editor used for editing an html page]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause, but I'm guessing it's a z-index issue. Check the z-index of the element that is hiding the CKEditor dialog first. If it's for example 11000, try a bigger number for the base z-index for CKEditor like below, it might help.

```
config.baseFloatZIndex = 12000;
```

If the issue is not fixed, try digging some more in the element layers to see what order they are rendered in. Firefox has a really nice 3d view in it's developer tools for this inspection.

By the way, giving us a version number and a link to the problem helps.